# PHP: How to know if a user is currently downloading a file?

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm developing a quick rapidshare-like site where the user can download files. First, I created a quick test setting headers and using `readfile()` but then I found [in the comments section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#83653) there's a way to limit the speed of the download, which is great, here's the code:

```
$local_file = 'file.zip';
$download_file = 'name.zip';

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
$download_rate = 20.5;
if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file))
{
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

    flush();
    $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        // send the current file part to the browser
        print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
        // flush the content to the browser
        flush();
        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($file);}
else {
    die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}
```

But now my question is, how to limit the number of downloads at the same time? How can I check there's still a connection with some user's IP?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use screaming 'PURCHASE ACCOUNT FOR FASTER DOWNLOAD AND NO WAITING TIME' advertisements. I beg you.

Comment: I'll try to come with something more original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does a user have a login? if not just use sessions, or even better track on their ip-address.

Here's a sessions example:

```
$_SESSION['file_downloading']==true;
$file = fopen($local_file, "r");
while(!feof($file))
{
    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();
    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}
$_SESSION['file_downloading']=null;
fclose($file);}
```

Then above all this code,

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['file_downloading']))
```

//perform a redirect or reduce their download rate or something.

Next option is via ip address.

```
//http://wiki.jumba.com.au/wiki/PHP_Get_user_IP_Address
function VisitorIP()
    { 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $TheIp=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else $TheIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    return trim($TheIp);
    }
```

get the visitor ip address, store this in the database along with the datetime stamp. Then simply remove that ip address when the file is finished downloading. Are you using a database system?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['file_download']) && $_SESSION['file_downloading'])` → `if (!empty($_SESSION['file_downloading']))` :)